# How to clear a text field when "return" is pressed on the on screen keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a button that is supposed to add text from a TextField into a list, either when the button is pressed, or "return" is pressed on the on-screen keyboard, and then clear the TextField. When I press the button this all works flawlessly, however when I press "return" the item gets added onto the list but the TextField is never cleared. I do not understand why it does not get cleared, the same code is called when "return" is pressed as when the button is pressed.

```
TextField("Add Item", text: $newItem, onCommit: {
                    self.items.append(self.newItem)
                    ShoppingListData.saveItems(self.items)
                    self.newItem = ""
                })
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                .padding(.vertical, 6)
                .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                .cornerRadius(10)

                Button(action: {
                    self.items.append(self.newItem)
                    ShoppingListData.saveItems(self.items)
                    self.newItem = ""
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
```

As you can see both the button and the onCommit use the same code

```
                    self.items.append(self.newItem)
                    ShoppingListData.saveItems(self.items)
                    self.newItem = ""
```

However for some reason the `self.newItem = ""` only works when the button is pressed and not when "return" is pressed and onCommit is called.

I've looked up online how to clear text fields and as far as I am aware `self.newItem = ""` should be clearing the text field but it does not.

Answer (score 1):

**---- In SwiftUI ----**

We can use textField modifier 'onCommit', its action is set to clear the text by setting self.text to an empty string.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter text here", text: $text) {
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 self.text = ""
             }
        }
    }
}
```

**---- In UIKit ----**

You need implement the **textFieldShouldReturn** method, which is called when the "return" key is pressed on the on-screen keyboard. In this method, we clear the text field by setting its text property to an empty string.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    // Set the text field's delegate to self
    yourTextField.delegate = self

// UITextFieldDelegate method called when the "return" key is pressed
  func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Clear the text field
    textField.text = ""

// Hide the keyboard
      textField.resignFirstResponder()
      return true
   }
}
```

Comment: he's using swiftUI, this would not work

Comment: edited for SwiftUI

Comment: Nice! The key to solve the issue was to use this async call. Maybe there's some SwiftUI Rendering stuff that prevents the text from being clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can add  UIApplication.shared.endEditing() code in your Button:

```
Button(action: {
                self.items.append(self.newItem)
                ShoppingListData.saveItems(self.items)
                self.newItem = ""
               UIApplication.shared.endEditing() // Call to dismiss keyboard
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }
```

and add this extension:

```
// extension for keyboard to dismiss
extension UIApplication {
    func endEditing() {
        sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Nope, the text still doesn't clear from the TextField